# Proving $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)$ are equivalent using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

In Spivak's *Calculus*, he asks for a proof that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)$.

He first shows that the existence of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ implies the existence and equivalence of $\lim_{h\to0}f(a+h)$, and then he says the argument for the other direction is "similar," but I am having a hard time replicating it (I may be getting unnecessarily bogged down in notational issues). His proof of the first direction is essentially as follows:

> **(Spivak forward direction):** Let $\ell=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and define $g(h)=f(a+h)$. Then for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that, for all $x$, if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-\ell|<\epsilon$. Now, if $0<|h|<\delta$, then $0<|(a+h)-a|<\delta$, so $|f(a+h)-\ell|<\epsilon$, which we can write as $|g(h)-\ell|<\epsilon$. Thus, $\lim_{h\to0}g(h)=\ell$, which can also be written $\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)=\ell$.
>
> The same sort of argument shows that if $\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)=m$, then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=m$. So either limit exists if the other does, and in this case they are equal.

**My attempt at other direction:** Let $m=\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)$. Then for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ for all $h$ such that if $0<|h|<\delta$ then $|f(a+h)-m|<\epsilon$. Now, if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(a+(x-a))-m|=|f(x)-m|<\epsilon$. Thus, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=m$.

What am I missing here? Is my proof okay? Why does Spivak use the function $g$ in the previous direction? Is it really necessary? What would such a $g$ be in the other direction?

Comment: I wrote up a short proof [here](http://i.imgur.com/MSZAVnx.png) that does not make use of an auxiliary function $g$. Can anyone attest to its correctness or lack thereof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You *feel* like having missed something in your proof due to the absence of an auxiliary function (as in the forward direction).  However, there's *nothing* missed in your proof.
- Your proof is correct.
- In the classical $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of limits, for educational purposes, one writes $\dots |f(x)-\ell|<\varepsilon$: there's only *one* variable $x$ inside the bracket.  The author relabeled $f(a+h)$ as $g(h)$ so that

  - readers understand it's a function of $h$ with $a$ *fixed*.
  - the *form* $|g(h)-\ell|<\varepsilon$ *looks* like the book definition more like $|f(a+x)-\ell|<\varepsilon$.  Though they both represent the *same* quantity, the author preferred the former for newcomers.
- That's *not* necessary.  Once you're familiar with the logic, feel free to skip the setup of an auxiliary function to gain time.  Your teachers will understand the logic.
- Since the purpose of the auxiliary function is to simplify what's inside the bracket into one single variable, so that the relabeled function resembles symbolically a bit more to the classic $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of limits.  Therefore, I don't think changing the direction of the proof will change the way that the auxiliary function $g$ is defined.  We still have $g(x)=f(a+x)$ in the other half of the proof.  The difference is that in the forward direction of the proof, $g$ lives in "another side of the river", while in the  you "see" $g$ at the very first moment.

Comment: Thorough analysis of OP's proof +1